# how to bind Lighting-input with javascript Object

Tags: lightning, lighting-web-component

I have been working on Custom Component where I need to show the Opp detail and OppLineItems. I can't work with Lightning-edit-form etc because field labels should be different and other challenges, I landed up lighting-input. I need to fetch the Opp and OppLineItems and display them on Component

```
    <template>
        <lightning-card title="New Quote" icon-name="standard:quotes" variant="base">
            <div slot="actions">
                <lightning-button class= "slds-theme_inverse slds-button_outline-brand" icon-position="left" variant="brand" label="Back to Opportunity" icon-name="standard:return_order"></lightning-button>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-card__body_inner">
                <div style="font-size: 0.8125rem;">
                    <p>Review the details to submit the Quote</p>
                </div>
                <lightning-layout horizontal-align="space" multiple-rows="true">
                 
                        <lightning-input  name = 'quoteName' label="Quote Name" value = {oppObject.Name} read-only="true" type="text"  variant="standard"></lightning-input>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                   
                </lightning-layout>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Case List" icon-name="standard:case">
        <div class="slds-m-around_small">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={result}
                show-row-number-column
                hide-checkbox-column
                columns={columnsList}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
export default class getQuoteDetails extends LightningElement {
   
  @api recordId; 
  opportunities;
  oppObject;
  @track error;

  columnsList = columns;
  
  connectedCallback(){
    this.getOpportunityDetail();   
  };

  getOpportunityDetail(){
    fetchOpportunityDetails({ opportunityId: this.recordId })
        .then(data => {
            this.opportunities = data;
            this.oppObject = this.opportunities[0];
            console.log('Opportunities', this.oppObject);
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            window.console.log(' error ', error);
            this.oppObject = undefined;
        });    
  }

}


public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunityDetails( Id opportunityId){
        try {
            system.debug('Line Items Methid called--' + opportunityId);
            return [Select Id,Name,Expiry_date__c,Amount,
                    (SELECT Id,OpportunityId,Sales_Type__c,
                    Discount__c, Opportunity_Product_Count__c,ListPrice 
                    FROM OpportunityLineItems)
                    FROM Opportunity where Id=: opportunityId];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

For some reason, I am not getting the data in the Component. Can I get the data from {oppObject.Name} in the component.

Question --
1.
What's the best way to get the data from Apex, and bind it with Lighting-input
2. How to bind the javascript Object with lightning-input. I have searched for examples but those are binding the variable, not the Object to the component.

Comment: you can still use lightning-record-edit form component, and onload, simply traverse the object, iterate over the fields and display in a custom component with custom fields and labels.

Comment: @glls I didn't get you.. Could You please elaborate with a little example?Thanks

Comment: record edit form leverages the record-ui api,  this means that you can get your record(s) data using the onload event from the record edit form, you should lookup the component documentation.

Comment: ohk.. You are suggesting using lighting-input and custom Component. but I can just put the record-edit form to get the data. Is this the right understanding? why? Getting data is not a problem. I am calling a method in the connected callback and can see data in console. the problem is to bind it with lightning-input. I am binding an object instead of a variable.